# Import Export Wizard keep Identity, No Alter Table permissions

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Basically, I am transferring data from one database `table(A)` to another database `table(B)`.
Both databases have data except `A` gets updated daily and `B` needs to be updated with the current data in `A`. I would like to keep the identity column the same in both.

I try to run the wizard with delete previous data and the keep identity checked, but I get an error saying I don't have permission to alter table, so I am thinking that delete previous data truncates the table correct?

I then tried to use append table, but that complains about overwriting row with same identity value. Is there a way to ignore previous entries and only insert the new entries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, in your SELECT statement where you get data from table A, just select rows where A.ID is  not equal to B.ID.

This functionality might work better with a trigger on table A or using transactional replication.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that, duh! I will look into the other two options you have provided thank you!